# How to write a demo page that will provide the code of itself?

Tags: javascript, html, self, demo

Suppose you've made a demo(a webpage) of your product, you want to make a page to display the demo, and in the bottom of the page, there is a button by click which you can display the source code of the demo above. How to do this job nicely?

Comment: Just the html/css/javascript, or the server-side code as well?

Answer (score 1):

The following should work at least in Firefox (via [XMLSerializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLSerializer)), Internet Explorer, Chrome and Safari (via [outerHTML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534310%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). In browsers that support neither it will fall back to `innerHTML` with the disadvantage being that the root element itself (`<html>`) isn't included.

```
function getMyCode()
{
  if ("XMLSerializer" in window)
    return new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(document.documentElement);
  else if ("outerHTML" in document.documentElement)
    return document.documentElement.outerHTML;
  else
    return document.documentElement.innerHTML;
}
```

Then again, if you want the "real" source code rather than the serialized version of the DOM you won't get around downloading it again - the browser doesn't necessarily store it. You can use [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/XMLHttpRequest):

```
function getMyCode()
{
  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  req.open("GET", window.location.href);
  req.onreadystatechange = function()
  {
    if (this.readyState != 4)
      return;
    alert(this.responseText);
  };
  req.send(null);
}
```

Comment: I want the source code(what you see use right-click-view-page-source),  but IIRC the innerHTML is the DOM(what you see with Chrome developer tools)

Answer (score 0):

Make the request to the same page and ensure that the server responds with Content-Type set to "text/plain" instead of "text/html". If it is a server side script, then you can use query parameters to determine when to set Content-Type to "text/html" or "text/plain". If it is a static web page, you can make different URIs with different content types.